# C boolean logic

Tags: c#, c, boolean-logic

I have been trying some programs in the C Language and come across to this...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int j = 3, k;
    k= !5 && j;
    printf("%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone figure out what is the problem in this if I compile the program I will result to 0.

and when I tried the same code in C#

```
public void logic()
{
    j = 5;
    k = !4 && j;
    Console.WriteLine("hence the value would be " + k);
}
```

this will generate the error

> ( Error    1   Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int' C:\Documents and Settings\SANDEEP\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\ConsoleApplication18\ConsoleApplication18\Program.cs 21  17  ConsoleApplication18 )

I want to know why the output of my C code is not working, and how can I use the `!` operator in C#.
Please help.

Comment: The C program is behaving correctly by outputting 0. What do you expect it to do ?

Comment: Are these in the same program?

Comment: To answer your second question, it seems that c# (unlike c) doesn't allow treating integers as booleans.

Comment: C# is not the same as C++
C++ compilers can compile C code, try one of those instead of a C# compiler.

Comment: Edited this to remove SHOUTING in caps lock....sigh...ever hear of net etiquette.....no text speak here please - we speak and read English.....

Comment: @Martin: contrary to popular belief, C++ compilers in general can't compile C code; both languages share a common subset, though, which makes it possible to write code which can be compiled with compilers for both languages

Comment: @sandy101: When you ask a question about soemthing "not working", you have to explain what made you believe it is not working and how you expect it to work. Your C program works fine, as it should. So when you describe the *correct* behavior of the program and assert that it is "not working"... Well, it sounds like nonsense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C, any non-zero value such as `5` is considered to be "true", therefore `!5` evaluates to `0`, or "false". Thus, `0 && 3` is false as well. [Logical operators in C](http://www.itee.uq.edu.au/~comp2303/Leslie_C_ref/C/SYNTAX/logical.html).

In C#, the type system is a little stronger in this respect. The `!` operator only works on values of type `bool`, which is completely independent of the integer types. See [! Operator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2%28VS.80,loband%29.aspx).

Comment: +1; to be precise: any non-zero scalar value is considered 'true'

Answer (score 9):

`5` when interpreted as a boolean value is true, so`!5` gives the boolean result false, which causes `&&` to give false as well. False interpreted as an `int` is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The readable C code:
Compile it, run it, and how the expressions are evaluated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        int j = 3, k;
        k = !5 && j;

        printf("!5 = %d \n", !5);
        printf("j = %d \n", j);
        printf("!5 && j = %d \n", !5 && j);
        printf("k = %d \n",k);

        return 0;
}
```

You probably cannot apply "!" to ints in C# in this manner. I believe you can achieve that by using "~" on an int.
You can aply "!" to a Boolean (I don't know how it's called in C#).

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent code to this C code

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int j=3,k; 
    k=!5&&j; 
    printf("%d",k); 
    return 0; 
}
```

in C# would be

```
class Program {
static int Main() 
{ 
    int j=3, k; 
    k = !(5 != 0) && (j != 0) ? 1 : 0; 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", k); 
    return 0; 
}
}
```

Notice that C# does not allow Boolean logic operators to be used on ints. If you want to convert ints to bools, you'll have to write code to do that, as I have here.

Both programs correctly output zero because 5 is not equal to 0, therefore !5 (C) or !(5!=0) (C#) is false. In C, the false converts to zero. In C#, the alternative of the conditional operator gives zero.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

> and how can i use the ! operator in c#.

That's the logical-not operator. You put it to the right of a `bool` and it produces the opposite. In C# there is no implicit conversion from integer to `bool`.

By the way, your "same code" in C# has different number values in it!

Comment: And, if you really want to achieve the same effect of the C logical-not on numbers in C# just use number==0.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a logical NOT.  You have to do a bitwise NOT on an int in C# (the ~ operator, not !).  See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C# (and Java) you could do something like

```
k = (4 == 0) && (j != 0);
```

to get the same behaviour as your C program. Comparing an integer to 0 gives the same "logics" than C.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do bit arithmetic rather than simple boolean arithmetic, your C code is using the wrong operators. Here's a [sample link](http://www.itee.uq.edu.au/~comp2303/Leslie_C_ref/C/CONCEPT/bitwise.html) with the correct operators.

In your current C code, k=!5&&j, 5 is considered true, so !5 is 0 (false). You then AND it with j, but any false ANDed with any boolean is false, so you get 0.

You probably want something like (tilda5)&j

Comment: The title says C boolean logic, not C bitwise operations.

Comment: @fusbar The title was edited by me. The original specified only "logic".